# Por que Efetuar UPDATE com JOIN não obedece a condicional WHERE

Tags: sql-server

Efetuarei a substituição de valores de uma coluna na tabela A por valores da tabela B, sendo condicionadas por uma coluna da tabela C.

Ao efetuar o UPDATE, a condicional não está sendo respeitada e todos os valores estão sendo alterados.

```
UPDATE
    tabela_precos_produtos
SET
    valor_canal = pg.jan_valor, 
    valor_partida = pg.dez_valor
FROM
    precos_geral pg
JOIN 
    tabela_precos tp ON cod_tabela = cod_tabela
WHERE
    tp.uf = 'SP'
```

Como deve ser feito o UPDATE obedecendo o caso mencionado? A query acima não traz o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que vc esqueceu de colocar no join a tabela que quer alterar, tente:

```
UPDATE tpp
SET valor_canal = pg.jan_valor, 
    valor_partida = pg.dez_valor
FROM precos_geral pg
INNER JOIN tabela_precos tp ON tp.cod_tabela = pg.cod_tabela
INNER JOIN tabela_precos_produtos tpp ON tpp.<campo1> = tp.<campo2>
WHERE
    tp.uf = 'SP'
```

Não sei se o join correto é esse (tpp com tp), mas acho que dá para ter uma ideia.